# Complete small business package linux

Tags: linux, small-business, packages

I'm looking for some sort of pack, for small business? We've got one server, but I need some sort of pack including Apache 2, MySQL, PHP, SMTP and POP3/IMAP?
I'd prefer if I could get some sort of control panel?

Is there any standard server package for this purpose? Or should everything be installed individually?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware there's no "small business server" distribution. However, you can easily install [Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server edition](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server) (the "LTS" stands for "Long Term Support" - this is generally what you want when you're running servers. You can then install/configure your LAMP stack individually (the Ubuntu installer even provides a group-install open I believe).

For control panels, take a look at [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) (free) or [Plesk](http://www.parallels.com/products/plesk/) or [Cpanel](http://cpanel.net/) (both commercial, paid software). Apache and MySQL can be installed using your chosen distribution's package manager.

For mail-server software, you can use a combination of Postfix (SMTP) and Dovecot (POP3/IMAP) with SpamAssassin and ClamAV for spam filtering and virus-scanning respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if there's any package containing everything you're asking for but you should check out [LAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)), it contains Apache, MySQL, PHP and/or Perl/Python.